# How do I add a weather overlay in Apple Clips?

Tags: ios, clips.app

The [location permissions text](https://twitter.com/KhaosT/status/850163981968842752) for Apple's Clips app says

> Your […] weather will be displayed in overlays you can add to your videos.

How dow I add weather overlays to my videos?

Comment: Don't think this functionality is included currently.